# How overload int + object C++?

Tags: c++

How can I overload the operator of an int + object?
In the reverse way, object + int I know.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "prueba.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int numero = 5;
Prueba number(9);
//int numero2 = numero + number;
int numero2 = number + numero;
cout << numero2 << endl;
return 0;
}
```

prueba.h

```
#include <iostream>

class Prueba
{
private:
int numero;
public:
Prueba(int numero);
friend int operator+(int numero, const Prueba& prueba);
int operator+(int numero)const;
int getNumero()const;
};
```

prueba.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "prueba.h"

Prueba::Prueba(int numero)
{
this->numero = numero;
return;
}

int operator+(int numero, const Prueba prueba)
{
int resultado;
resultado = numero+prueba.getNumero();
return resultado;
}

int Prueba::operator+(int numero)const
{
int resultado;
resultado = this->numero + numero;
return resultado;
}

int Prueba::getNumero()const
{
return this->numero;
}
```

The line commented with // is the one that I can not solve.
I tried to solve it with the method int operator + (int number, const Test test)

Comment: Overload `operator int()` (and all other implicit conversions you need) for your class? see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator

Comment: [This canonical operator overload implementations reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Canonical_implementations) might be helpful.

Comment: I'm not the downvote on this, but I wouldn't be surprised if it's because the question is part spanish. Please make an effort to write testcases in a format that will enable others to help you. It's incredibly rude to have people jump hoops to understand your question. (alternatively, there's a [spanish stackoverflow sister site](http://es.stackoverflow.com/), you can post there if you're only interested in spanish people helping).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to overload the int addition.

```
struct n { int x; };

int operator + (int lhs, n rhs)
{
    return lhs + rhs.x;
}
```